# Compute $\int_{\gamma(-1;2)} \frac{dz}{(z^2+z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I'm trying to compute the following integral: $$\int_{\gamma(-1;2)} \frac{dz}{(z^2+z)^2}$$ where $\gamma$ is traversed twice in a clockwise direction. I know that I can compute this integral using Cauchy's residue theorem, but my question is how do I deal with the fact that the circle is traversed twice and in a clockwise direction?

My assumption would be that I compute the integral as if it were positively oriented and only traversed once and then multiply this result by $-2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Wait: what does $\;\gamma(-1,2)\;$ mean? I though that is the circle with center at $\;-1\;$ and radius $\;2\;$, but apparently it means something else and you say the path, whatever it is, is traversed twice...

Comment: Unit circle centered at $-1$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean for  $\gamma(-1,2)$ to denote the circle centered at $-1$ of radius $2$.

Comment: @Ok, so the fact that it is traversed twice is *given* . Thanks. And then yes: your idea in the last lines is correct, and that's exactly what the most general Cauchy's Residue Theorem tells. Take a peek for example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem